# Intermittent bug - IE6 showing file as text in browser, rather than as file download

Tags: asp.net, webforms, download

In an ASP.NET WebForms 2.0 site we are encountering an intermittent bug in IE6 whereby a file download attempt results in the contents of the being shown directly in the browser as text, rather than the file save dialog being displayed. Our application allows the user to download both PDF and CSV files.

The code we're using is:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"theFilename.pdf\"");
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.BinaryWrite(MethodThatReturnsFileContents());
response.End();
```

This is called from the code-behind click event handler of a button server control.

Where are we going wrong with this approach?

### Edit

Following James' answer to this posting, the code I'm using now looks like this:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearHeaders();
// Setting cache to NoCache was recommended, but doing so results in a security
// warning in IE6
//response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"theFilename.pdf\"");
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.BinaryWrite(MethodThatReturnsFileContents());
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

However, I don't believe that any of the changes made will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The glib answer is you're going wrong by supporting IE6....

`Response.Clear` only clears content from the response, use `Response.ClearHeaders` instead.

Other than that, you might want to look at using `Response.Buffer` & `Response.Flush` and explicitly setting

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Personally I might want to add content length and charset to my headers as the more info the browser has to work with the better.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx

Comment: Also, AddHeader is old school ASP, in .NET you should use AppendHeader instead. Not sure why exactly.

Comment: But...can you account for the intermittent nature of the bug?

Comment: Well if the problem was caused by cached data or uncleared headers then I might expect the browser to behave unpredictably, as the actual output would be variable. It might be worth trying to get hold of the exact HTTP headers you're outputting in both cases and comparing them.

Comment: If I `SetCacheability` to `NoCache` the IE6 file download dialog picks up a "security warning" note, and doesn't display the file type icon, file name or file type correctly. The headers also change - `Cache-Control` is set to `no-cache` (which I expect), but two additional headers are present, `Expires: -1` and `Pragma: no-cache`. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I don't know why the security warning, file type icon or file name & type go wrong, but Pragma and Expires: -1 are both methods of ensuring cacheing is turned off (pragma from http 1.0, I think), so they're both fine. Reading around on PDF/IE6 here I can see people recommending adding a bit of querystring to the URL such as filename=myfile.pdf to give IE a hint. Can you give us a snapshot of what your code looks like now, just to see if there's anything obviously in the wrong place?

Comment: Also, I can see that stopping cacheing causes IE6 to go quite buggy with filenames etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868976/file-download-in-ie6-gets-the-wrong-filename

Comment: And a space between attachment; and filename might help.