# chm file downloads issue

Tags: download, chm

I have content with mime type set as application/x-chm, which as I understand it, enable downloading of chm files.
However when I select the link which triggers the save/open file dialog the .chm file extension is not resolved and I have to explicitly add the .chm file extension for the file to be saved.
How can I get the .chm file extension to resolved automatically?

Comment: How does the code which "trigger the download" look like? What headers are send?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [official IANA document](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp), the MIME-type for `.chm` files is `application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp`.

*Side note, you never know for sure how the file is being displayed to the user, since the user can choose how to display a file themselves.*

Comment: Thanks for your response Rob. Unfortunately changing the mime type still has no effect. In response to your comment above I don't have control of the code which handles the download I only have access to the code which loads the content to our database. Pdfs, which are downloaded in the same manner and have a mime type set to application/pdf work as expected.

Comment: @MarkWalsh By headers, I mean the (server) response headers. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2868976 (I was referring to `filename=...`). These headers can be inspected in various devtools, e.g. in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4423061.

Comment: For chm files the header has Content-Type = application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp and Content-Disposition = attachment; filename="payload". While for pdf files the header has Content-Type = application/pdf and Content-Disposition = attachment; filename="payload".

Comment: Did it occur to you to use `filename="payload.chm"`? I can confirm that `.pdf` is automatically added using your headers (Chrome 18).

Comment: Ah yes, this is the thing. If the download file name retains a .chm file extension all is fine. However, in the instance I have outlined, the .chm files are given aliases which don't contain the .chm file extension and I don't have access to the code base which handles this, only the code which loads the data to the DB. So it looks like I am out of luck but thanks for all the help Rob, much appreciated.